# How to read the changes in UISwitch in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

Although I've found similar questions asked, I'm not able to comprehend the answers for it.

How would we read the changes in `UISwitch` or for that matter any element while in a `UITableViewCell`? Tried using a protocol, but the custom cell class complains about no initialisers. Used, a delegate, which seems to not conform to the view controller.

```
protocol SwitchTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didChangeSwitchValue(value: Bool)
}

class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var delegate: SwitchTableViewCellDelegate
var value: Bool =  true

@IBOutlet weak var switchCellLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var switchCellSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBAction func changedSwitchValue(sender: UISwitch) {
    self.value = sender.on
    delegate.didChangeSwitchValue(value)
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
                cell.delegate = self
                cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Show Cloud Music"
                cell.switchCellSwitch.on = userDefaults.boolForKey(cloudMusicKey)
```

Any suggestions, on how to implement this?

Comment: Show how are you implementing the delegate callback.

Comment: Actually, I'm new to iOS dev, and am trying to piece up everything. Not sure, if this has to happen in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.. ?

Comment: show the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Included as requested

Comment: @Shyam In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`you have Multi types of cell?

Comment: @NiravD. Yes, I do..

Comment: @Shyam Can you show whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Are you having fixed number of cell?

Comment: @NiravD, thanks.. It has all been worked out..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using a Swift closure for this. Use the following code in your cell class:

```
class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var callback: ((switch: UISwitch) -> Void)?
var value: Bool =  true

@IBOutlet weak var switchCellLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var switchCellSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBAction func changedSwitchValue(sender: UISwitch) {
    self.value = sender.on
    callback?(switch: sender)
}
```

Then this code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
cell.callback = { (switch) -> Void in 
    // DO stuff here.
}
cell.switchCellLabel?.text = "Show Cloud Music"
cell.switchCellSwitch.on = userDefaults.boolForKey(cloudMusicKey)
```

Comment: I wouldn't need a delegate, then?

Comment: No you wouldn't need the delegate, you can use the Swift closure pattern just like this ^^^.

Comment: Also you won't be able to call variables `switch` as this is a reserved keyword in Swift.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could be of help. :)

Comment: The easiest way to do this (grey the cell out and stop the user interacting with it's contents) would be to just add a subview to the cell on top of all the other views with a background colour of black and an alpha of say 0.5.

Comment: It's possibly not the _best_ solution, but it is quick and tidy.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it with an extension?

Comment: Probably my question was vague!! :/ cell.switchCellSwitch.enabled = false did what I wanted...

Comment: Jacob, is it possible to change the footer using a similar logic? I'm not able to do it. if userDefaults.boolForKey(cloudMusicKey) == true {
                return "Music available in the cloud is also shown."
            } else {
                return "Music available only on the device is shown."
            } is used in `titleForFooterSection`, but the change is observed only while the viewController is loaded again, not immediately..

Comment: The section would need to be reloaded to update the footer. So in the callback block you could call `tableView.reloadSections([NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)`

Comment: Thanks very much.. :) :) Although, I have to suggest a small typo. `tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)` , [ ] removed for NSIndexSet.. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah excuse my typos haha, I wrote that outside of the Xcode text editor and therefore had to try and remember the exact syntax! :P

Comment: No worries.. Had to highlight, just in case anyone refers it.. :-p

Comment: Jacob, if `reloadSections` is used more than once, `tableView` gets messed up, while scrolling!! Not sure, if you've encountered this. You should try and see the result. Looks like, it's a problem with the way the method is, or the way I use it..

Comment: Awesome! Elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since there can be many cells sharing the same delegate, the delegate should know which cell calls it. Hence, your protocol method should provide the cell itself, not just its switch value. In fact, we can omit the switch value parameter since it can be queried from the cell.

```
protocol SwitchTableViewCellDelegate {
    func switchTableViewCellDidChangeSwitchValue(cell: SwitchTableViewCell)
}
```

In your delegate's implementation of the protocol method, you can access the switch value like this:

```
func switchTableViewCellDidChangeSwitchValue(cell: SwitchTableViewCell) {
    let switchValue = cell.value
}
```

Secondly, the delegate property can be nil so its type must be an `Optional`.

```
var delegate: SwitchTableViewCellDelegate?
```

To call the delegate when `value` changes:

```
delegate?.switchTableViewCellDidChangeSwitchValue(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll go with closure for my current scenario. Its simpler..